# applying a mask to matrices gives different objects in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I've mostly worked with MATLAB, and I am converting some of my code that I have written into Python. I am running into an issue where I have a boolean mask that I am calling Omega, and when I apply the mask to different m by n matrices that I call X and M I get different objects. Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA

m = 4
n = 3
r = 2
A = np.matrix('1 0; 0 1; 1 1;1 2')
B = np.matrix('1 1 2; 0 1 1')
M = A @ B
Omega = np.matrix('1 1 1;1 1 1;1 1 0;1 0 0',dtype=bool) #mask

X = np.copy(M)
X[~Omega] = 0

U, S, Vh = LA.svd(X) #singular value decompostion of X
Sigma = np.zeros((m,n))
np.fill_diagonal(Sigma,S)
X = U[:,0:r] @ Sigma[0:r,0:r] @ Vh[0:r,:]
print(X[Omega])
print(M[Omega])
X[Omega] = M[Omega]
```

I get the error "NumPy boolean array indexing assignment requires a 0 or 1-dimensional input, input has 2 dimensions" on the last line. However, the issue seems to be that X[Omega] and M[Omega] are different objects, in the sense that there are single brackets around X[Omega] and double brackets around M[Omega]. In particular, the print commands print out

```
[0.78935751 1.12034437 2.01560085 0.4845614  0.72316014 0.96411184 1.10709648 1.93881358 0.24918864]
[[1 1 2 0 1 1 1 2 1]]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Single brackets mean it's 1d, shape (9,).  Double brackets is 2d (one pair per dimension), shape (1,9).  `np.matrix` objects always have 2d shape, like (old) MATLAB.  `ndarray` (numpy array) may be 1d (or even 0d).  Generally we encourage the use of `np.array` rather than `np.matrix`, through for some people the transition from MATLAB is easier with `matrix`.

Comment: To convert M to an array, you can use `np.asarray(M[Omega])[0,:]` or `np.asarray(M[Omega]).reshape(-1)`.

Comment: Even when I worked with MATLAB years ago, I found that keeping track of dimensions was 80% of the (debugging) battle.  That's still the case when converting from MATLAB to `numpy`.  Don't make assumptions - verify the shape (and dtype) at each step.

Comment: @TimRoberts, `np.matrix` objects have a `.A1` property that streamlines fetching a 1d array from a matrix.

Comment: Wow @hpaulj - that's quite something! I updated my answer to use `A1` (if you don't mind, that is).

Comment: Thanks for that tidbit, @hpaulj.  I didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M` is a `np.matrix`, which are always 2-D (so it has two dimensions). As the error message indicates, you can only use a 0- or 1-D array when assigning to an array masked with a boolean mask (which is what you're doing).

Instead, convert `M` to an array first (which, as [@hpaulj pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71564655/applying-a-mask-to-matrices-gives-different-objects-in-numpy/71564739#comment126483534_71564655), is better than using `asarray` + `ravel`)

```
X[Omega] = M[Omega].A1
```

Output:

```
>>> X
array([[ 1.        ,  1.        ,  2.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  2.        , -0.00793191],
       [ 1.        ,  0.42895392,  0.05560748]])
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the problem is that X is a 2D array instead of a matrix? How can I tell the difference? Should I just make all my matrices arrays instead from the start?

Comment: There's no need to make them all matrices - `.A1` was designed for this scenario. The issue at hand is that `X[Omega] = ZZZ` only works if `ZZZ` is 0D or 1D, but matrixes are inherently 2D.